# Nginx desconectando dois subdominios

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php-7.1

Olá, estou tendo problemas com dois subdominios, verifiquei o tail encontrei este erro: 
2018/06/15 13:02:11 [error] 13456#13456: *807 connect() to unix:/var/run/php7.1-fpm-esf.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: ip-x, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php7.1-fpm-esf.sock:"